# How do I connect between two queries using inner join (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries (z1 and z2) and I want to JOIN them into one using the NAME as the connector.

```
select * from 
(SELECT a.num, a.company, stopb.name
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num<br />)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
where stopa.name = 'Craiglockhart') z1

join 

(SELECT a.num,a.company, stopa.name
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
where stopb.name = 'Lochend') z2 on z1.name = z2.name;
```

Why do I get an error `("The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay")`?

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: There may be a more efficient way to write this code.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the queries z1 and z2 have a very large number of rows because they are not unique by name.

For example, if company and num associated with name are unique, you should be able to get the results by adding DISTINCT to your queries.

```
select * from 
(SELECT DISTINCT a.num, a.company, stopb.name
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
where stopa.name = 'Craiglockhart') z1


join 
(SELECT DISTINCT a.num,a.company, stopa.name
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
where stopb.name = 'Lochend') z2 on z1.name = z2.name;
```

The queries z1 and z2 are very similar, so another approach might be more simplistic.
However, to do it, you need to provide table definitions and sample datas for your queries.